# what is the difference between creating reference name using class and using Interface

Tags: java

Could any one explain,what is the difference between creating reference name using  Object or  using Interface.

ex1

```
ArrayList li=new ArrayList();// creating reference  using class name
```

ex2

```
List li=new ArrayList()//creating reference  using interface name
```

In real scenario why developers using ex2?

What are the advantages for using ex2?

Comment: FWIW, in Java, these permit different sets of operations at compile-time, but have exactly the same implementation at runtime. In Go, the equivalent declarations are actually different at runtime - one passes by value, one by reference. Progress!

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is *programming to an interface*. It makes it clear that although you may be dependent on some aspects of the *behaviour* of the chosen implementation (e.g. its performance characteristics, or its sort order etc) you're only relying on the *members* declared in the interface. This generally makes it easier to later swap out one implementation with another.

(If you *are* relying on some very specific aspect of an implementation, I find it's usually a good idea to explicitly say so, to avoid surprises later.)

Comment: I wince a bit when i hear "programming to an interface" used to describe this. Yes, it is programming to an interface. But programming to an interface also means using a class in such a way that you rely only on its exposed details, not its hidden internals. Like how although i might know that `URL.equals` can be used to check if i have internet access, i wouldn't use it for that. Failure to separate these two meanings of interface can lead people to introduce unnecessary complexity in their code, because they think it's somehow bad to ever use classes as types. That and JMock.

Comment: @TomAnderson: I would call that "the public documented API of the class" rather than "interface". Given that the word "interface" does have a very strong language meaning in Java (and other languages such as C#) I think it's reasonable to use that meaning consistently, and use a different term when you're not *really* talking about interfaces from a Java terminology perspective.

Comment: The trouble is that "programming to an interface" is now an established phrase that is well established in the wild, and it *doesn't* refer to the language construct (at least, once didn't, and i think shouldn't - Steve McConnell expresses it really well in Code Complete). If we could atomically replace all uses of it with "programming to a public documented API" or "programming to a contract", then that would be superb. You could then say that the use of an interface is a way to promote programming to a contract. Sadly, such a replacement is beyond me!

Comment: My desire to separate these meanings usually leads to be following any mention of programming to an interface with an explanation of the two meanings and why the difference matters, which invariably results in the audience becoming confused and/or irritated. So i'm not sure my advice is to be weighed very heavily.

Answer (score 2):

It means you are coding to a contract and not an implementation. In your example the List contact. If later you need a different type of list all you need to do is change one line where you make your declaration. It makes making changes in the future easier.

If you need specific methods on ArrayList that aren't in list then using ex1 is valid. Although if you change from ArrayList it may be harder. This link may be useful http://jdevelopment.nl/java-best-practices-5-code-to-interface-access-by-name-and-instance-data/

Answer (score 0):

The second has much more advantages:

It is considered good style to store a reference to a `HashSet` or `TreeSet` in a variable of type Set. For example:

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
```

This way, you have to change only one line if you decide to use a TreeSet instead.

Also, methods that operate on sets should specify parameters of type Set:

```
public static void print(Set<String> s)
```

Then the method can be used for all set implementations.